# Can i be a corresponding author?

Tags: publications, supervision, conflict-of-interest

I am a PhD student now and i am willing to publish my masters degree research work, but the supervisor is refusing to publish for many reasons concerned him not the quality of my research.

There is no other way just to remove his name.

the question can i be a corresponding author ?

Thanks.

Comment: Your question is not about being a corresponding author but rather whether you could remove your supervisor from your paper. These are two VERY different aspects!

Comment: voting to close since the answer depends on those 'so many reasons' your supervisor is concerned about *and* your personal condition.

Answer (score 3):

If the work is yours and yours alone then you can do with it what you like.

However, a better question might be whether it would be wise to cut out your advisor. If you want to build a future for yourself in academia you should try to build bridges to your advisor, not blow them up. This is a political issue, not necessarily one of fairness.

But, your advisor should have more experience in these things than you do, so their opinion might actually be valid.

Also, if your work isn't yours alone, but was done in concert with others, including your advisor, then you actually *need* to come to a joint understanding in order to publish it without breaking ethical norms.

The answer to *can* I do this and *should* I do this aren't necessarily the same. Take a long view before you decide.

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing stopping you being the corresponding author on a submitted paper - I was several times during my PhD. But you can't submit a paper with your supervisor as a co-author without his agreement.

In general, it's worth listening to your supervisor. If he doesn't think the work should be submitted for publication there's probably a reason why. You don't specify what reason he's given you - that might be helpful to people trying to answer your question.